# How to pronounce the mathematical symbols?

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation

For example, 2 squared is 4
(1/4) cubed = one-quarter cubed = 1 over 64
... what will be next after squared and cubed?
2 to the 10th power is equal to 1024.
and why does "power" show up ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 and 3 are the only exponents that have special terms in English.

> - 2 squared is 4.
> - 4 is the square of 2.
> - 2 is the square root of 4.
> - 2 cubed is 8.
> - 8 is the cube of 2.
> - 2 is the cube root of 8.

For other exponents, we read the operation as "X (raised) to the N'th power" or "X (raised) to the power of N." The word "raised" is optional.

> - 2 to the 8th power is 256.
> - 2 is the 8th root of 256.
> - 2 to the power of 1.5 is approximately 2.828.

You can also use this form for squares and cubes; it isn't strictly necessary to use the special terms. I.e., "2 to the 2nd power is 4" is fine.

Wikipedia's [article on exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) explains the origin of "power" and related terms:

> The term *power* was used by the Greek mathematician Euclid for the square of a line, following Hippocrates of Chios. Archimedes discovered and proved the law of exponents, 10<sup>a</sup> ⋅ 10<sup>b</sup> = 10<sup>a+b</sup>, necessary to manipulate powers of 10. In the 9th century, the Persian mathematician Muhammad ibn Mūsā al-Khwārizmī used the terms *mal* for a square and *kahb* for a cube, which later Islamic mathematicians represented in mathematical notation as *m* and *k*, respectively, by the 15th century, as seen in the work of Abū al-Hasan ibn Alī al-Qalasādī.

English inherits a lot of mathematical terminology from Greek, Arabic and Persian origins.